# What is there in learning to ride a bicycle?

Tags: perception, learning

Why do we need to learn to ride a bicycle? We just need to pedal and move the handle. I don't think balancing needs to be learnt. What is the thing we need to learn to ride a bicycle or is it just telling the brain that it is ok? And why do we not forget cycling? Thank You.

Comment: Can you walk on your hands and walk on a cord? Can infants walk the moment their legs can hold them physically? They're just balancing acts according to your reasoning...

Comment: You should do some research on how balancing works. It is not just about holding your head straight. You can start here: [Balance (ability)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_(ability))

Answer (score 2):

Riding a bicycle is the clasical example of [procedural memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_memory).

> Procedural memory guides the processes we perform and most frequently
>   resides below the level of conscious awareness. When needed,
>   procedural memories are automatically retrieved and utilized for the
>   execution of the integrated procedures involved in both cognitive and
>   motor skills, from tying shoes to flying an airplane to reading.
>   Procedural memories are accessed and used without the need for
>   conscious control or attention.
>
> Procedural memory is created through procedural learning or, repeating
>   a complex activity over and over again until all of the relevant
>   neural systems work together to automatically produce the activity.
>   Implicit **procedural learning is essential for the development of any
>   motor skill or cognitive activity**.

When we learn to ride a bicycle, the brain is learning the [motor movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_control) necessary to maintain balance. This learning occurs mostly at the unconsious level, and this is probably the reason why you have the illusion that nothing is learnt.

> Motor control is the process by which humans and animals use their
>   brain/cognition to activate and coordinate the muscles and limbs
>   involved in the performance of a motor skill.

The procedural memory is a type of [long term memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_memory) which has a long lasting effect.